# Certain number of items in a list

Tags: r

I have this list

```
Mylist <- c("orange", "apple", "cherry")
```

And this data frame

```
df<- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), value = c("orange, peach, apple", "pineapple, mandarine, coconut", "cherry, peach"))
```

I wish to select the rows that *value* contains a certain number of elements in the list.

In this example, I wish to see the rows that have more than 0 elements in the least (at least 1). **However, 0 can be variable.**

So, my ideal output is

```
id             value
1          orange, peach, apple
3                 cherry, peach
```

I tried this but it doesn't give me the correct results.

```
df[sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$value), ","), function(x)  
  (x %in% Mylist)) > 0,];
```

I appreciate if someone advises me what is wrong with the above code.

Comment: `df[sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$value), ",") ,function(x) 
                                            any(tolower(Mylist) %in% x)), ]`

Comment: Thanks, but for the sake of simplicity I put 0 in this example. As I said, it can be 1,2,...

Comment: `any` would handle all the cases. It would work for anything > 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a `pattern` by `paste`ing the elements of 'Mylist' and check whether it is present in the 'value' column using 'grep' and subset the dataset object based on that

```
df[grepl(paste0("\\b(", paste(tolower(Mylist), collapse="|"), ")\\b"), tolower(df$value)),]
#  id                value
#1  1 orange, peach, apple
#3  3        cherry, peach
```

If we need it based on the count, then

```
library(stringr)
df[Reduce(`+`, lapply(Mylist, str_count, string = df$value)) > 1,]
#  id                value
#1  1 orange, peach, apple
```

Comment: Thanks, but for the sake of simplicity I put 0 in this example. As I said, it can be 1,2,...

Comment: @MFR  Sorry, I am not getting your comment

Comment: Let's say  this is what I want `(x %in% Mylist) > 2` instead of `(x %in% Mylist) > 0`

Answer (score 1):

One problem you have is that if you check: `strsplit(as.character(df$value), ",")[[1]]` you will see that it returns `# [1] "orange" " peach" " apple"` notice the space before peach and apple. Without changing your code a quick fix is to split on `", "`.

A second problem is that you have `"Cherry"` in the df but `"cherry"` in your list. %in% will only detect exact char string matches. You could use a function like `tolower()` if there is a reason for the difference in capitalisation.

Third is that `sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$value), ", "), function(x) (x %in% Mylist))` returns a list of bools and so it can't be interpreted by `>` (this is what the error message should be telling you) so you could change to `df[lapply(sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$value), ", "), fun), sum) > 0,]` to solve your problem with the least changes to your code.

Having said that it would be better to take a step back and create a function that returns a count of matching items and pass that function to lappy or sapply.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, I fixed the issues.